# Find records with a single common field, but different values for other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with this structure in SQL Server:

```
Promotions
======
id
promoId
customerId
dealPeriod
lob
```

I need to find groups of records where the promoId for the records are the same, but either customerId, dealPeriod, or lob are different.

So, I would be uninterested in returning this:

```
id    promoId     customerId    dealPeriod    lob
1     p00100            100           2013    PL
2     p00100            100           2013    PL
3     p00100            100           2013    PL
```

But I would want to return this group with a different value for lob:

```
id    promoId     customerId    dealPeriod    lob
1     p00101            100           2013    PL
2     p00101            100           2013    PL
3     p00101            100           2013    RT
```

Or this group with different customer Ids:

```
id    promoId     customerId    dealPeriod    lob
1     p00102            100           2013    PL
2     p00102            200           2013    PL
3     p00102            100           2013    PL
```

Or this group with different deal periods:

```
id    promoId     customerId    dealPeriod    lob
1     p00103            100           2013    PL
2     p00103            200           2014    PL
3     p00103            100           2013    PL
```

The following is what I tried:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.customerId, t1.promoId, t1.dealPeriod, t1.lob
FROM promotion t1
INNER JOIN promotion t2 ON t1.promoid = t2.promoid
WHERE (t1.customernumber <> t2.customernumber) 
OR (t1.dealPeriod <> t2.dealPeriod) 
OR (t1.lob <> t2.lob)
```

This returns records including those I don't want:

```
id    promoId     customerId    dealPeriod    lob
1     p00100            100           2013    PL
2     p00100            100           2013    PL
3     p00100            100           2013    PL
4     p00101            102           2013    RT
5     p00101            102           2013    RT
6     p00101            102           2013    RT
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort. Please show us what you've tried by updating your question with your code.

Comment: Updated with my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM Promotions p 
    JOIN Promotions q ON p.promoid = q.promoid AND p.id <> q.id
WHERE (p.customerId <> q.customerId) 
    OR (p.dealPeriod <> q.dealPeriod) 
    OR (p.lob <> q.lob)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working. I am returning groups, but the groups are containing the same values for PromoId, CustomerId, DealPeriod, and Lob. It's very similar to my attempt, I'm struggling to figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Can you explain with an example as in your second, third and fourth outputs the result has duplicates for all columns except id.

Comment: I updated my question to include the results from my query. Let me know if you need anythign further.

Comment: @ChrisHardie What are the rows you do not want in your result?

Comment: I do not want a group of records if each record in that group has the same promoId, customerId, and dealPeriod, and lob. Those four fields comprise the concept of a version (I didn't come up with this schema), but I am now having integrity issues, and need to discover which "versions" have been polluted. Let me know if I haven't been clear.

Comment: It's so straightforward once someone points it out! Thanks for all the effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
;With CTE
AS
 (
  SELECT * , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY promoId ORDER BY promoId)
  FROM Promotions
 )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
```

Comment: I am getting this error "The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'."

Comment: @ChrisHardie please update your answer and show what you are doing ??

Comment: I updated it recently, let me know if you need more information. A previous developer used the fields of promoId, customerId, DealPeriod, and lob to enforce the concept of a "version". We are now having data integrity issues, and I need to find the "versions" have been polluted with bad data. Let me know if I haven't been clear.

Comment: @ChrisHardie just noticed you already have a column by the name of ID in your table just, use some other Alias for the row-number in my suggested solution. see mu update now

Comment: Thanks for this, but this returns all records. I do not want to return records where they have the same promoId, customerId, dealPeriod, and lob. I only want records where they are grouped by their promoId, but there is a different value for at least one record in either the promoId, customerId, or dealPeriod. Perhaps there is no straightforward way to do this in SQL, I should look at coding a solution.